# Unable to start web server; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: ALLOW_ENCODED_SLASH

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, spring-mvc

I have been facing this issue on a spring boot project while starting main spring boot application

I am getting this error log:

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
[30m2022-03-25 16:07:49,833[0;39m [1;31mERROR[0;39m [[34mrestartedMain[0;39m] [33morg.springframework.boot.SpringApplication[0;39m: Application run failed
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: **Unable to start web server; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: ALLOW_ENCODED_SLASH**
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:163)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:577)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:732)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:414)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:302)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1303)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1292)
    at com.elsevier.rrexport.RRDecopuledExportApplication.main(RRDecopuledExportApplication.java:11)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: ALLOW_ENCODED_SLASH
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.<init>(Connector.java:271)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:200)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:182)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:160)
    ... 13 common frames omitted
```

Please let me know , what configuration I need to change.
I have already added:

```
System.setProperty("org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.UDecoder.ALLOW_ENCODED_SLASH", "true");
```

Also defined it in the application.properties:

```
org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.UDecoder.ALLOW_ENCODED_SLASH=true
```

Nothing seems to work. My [build.gradle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eTCvL.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

You are using a mixture of Tomcat modules. Some from Tomcat 10 and some from Tomcat 9. Rather than manually setting the versions in your `build.gradle` file, you should allow Spring Boot's dependency management to control the Tomcat version. This will ensure that you use a version of Tomcat that's compatible with the version of Spring Boot that you are using and also ensure that all of the Tomcat modules have the same version.

Note that Spring Boot 2.x is not compatible with Tomcat 10. Tomcat 10 is an implementation of the Servlet 5.0 specification which is part of Jakarta EE 9. to use Tomcat 10, you'll have to use Spring Boot 3 which is only available as milestones at the moment and will not be released until near the end of 2022.

Comment: thanks, this solved this solved the issue